# Prevent expo Video from resizing when double tapping

Tags: react-native, video, expo, expo-av

I'm using expo-av to play my videos on my react native app.
I have a like system. But when I double tap on my video, it just changes its size.

```
<Video ref={video}
     source={{uri: item.illustration}}
     useNativeControls
     style={{flex: 1, aspectRatio: 1}}
     resizeMode="cover"
     shouldPlay={true}
     isLooping={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found to do it:
set

```
useNativeControls={false}
```